# x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ options -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ seem to be broken in g++

Tags: shared-libraries, cross-compiling, mingw32

#### Overview

A SSCCE illustrating that **x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++** when building a shared library on OS-X for deployment on Windows fails to include **libstc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll**  and **libgcc_s_seh.dll** even when the options **-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++** are specified.

If this is a bug in mingw then I'd appreciate knowing how to report it.

The commands used to build the project are in the bash shell script file: **doit.sh**

```
# Clean up
rm -rf *.o *.dll Main.exe winlibs

# Cross compile for the Windows shared library
GPP=/usr/local/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
$GPP -c MyLib.cpp -o MyLib.win.o
$GPP  -shared -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o MyLib.dll *.win.o

# Build Application Main.exe
$GPP  -c Main.cpp -o Main.win.o
$GPP  -o Main.exe MyLib.dll Main.win.o
```

The program builds but when exectuted on Windows 10 reports **libstdc++-6.dll, libgcc_s_seh-1.dll** and **libwinpthread**-1.dll are missing.

The **-static-libgcc** and **-static-libstdc++** appear to make no difference to the getneralted shared library.

Copying the missing libaries from the mingw distribution into the same folder as the application allows the prgram to run as it should.

MyLib.h

```
extern int add (int a, int b);
```

MyLib.cpp

```
#include "MyLib.h"

extern int add (int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "MyLib.h" 

using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "add(51700, 73)=" << add(51700, 73) << endl;       
    return 0; 
}
```

Tool Versions

```
| Tool                       | Version               |
|----------------------------|-----------------------|
| MacBook Pro                | OS-X Catalina 10.15.6 |
| x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc/g++ | 9.3.0 (GCC) (download with brew install mingw-w64) |
| uname -a                   | Darwin michaels-mbp 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:49:00 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 |
```

GitLab URL

This project is public on GitLab at gitlab url: https://gitlab.com/Michael51773/mingwwindowssharedlibbug

Comment: Have you tried using simply `-static`? That should link all the needed libraries.

Comment: The options `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` aren't supposed to link the `libwinpthread-1` library. For me, a compiled program doesn't even report `libwinpthread-1` library missing if the other two are also missing. Are you sure you aren't missing only `libwinpthread-1` after linking the other two libraries with `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`?

Comment: Found a solution that worked for me with help from Adrian Ho (see below)

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Adrian Ho who gave me the solution, it was just a matter of using the -static AND the -shared option together:

```
/usr/local/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -static -o MyLib-static.dll MyLib/*.win.o
```

A full description can be found here: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/x86-64-w64-mingw32-g-broken-options-static-libgcc-static-libstdc/8705/22

Comment: Well, of course you also need `-shared`, because you are building a shared library. I thought that was obvious from your question description.

Comment: I had always had used the shard option, the confusion was that I had issued the -static option was for generating a static library and so incompatible with the -shared option whereas the -static option is to statically include dependent libraries whether you are making s shared or static product.